# PHAsset copy from one album to another

Tags: ios, swift, photo

I want to copy an asset from one album to another, without asking for imageData or videoData, that is, just copy an asset from one album to another

What I do

```
let asset = PHAsset.fetchAssets(withLocalIdentifiers: [assetLocalIdentifier], options: .none).firstObject
PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
    guard let albumChangeRequest = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest(for: album) else { return }
    albumChangeRequest?.addAssets([asset] as NSFastEnumeration)
})
```

album is my custom album

and im get crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString objectID]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x600002339340'
```

ofc asset exist, and album exist and all fine if im save video to file and use creationRequestForAssetFromVideo...

I have no problems with saving via creationRequestForAssetFromVideo, but for this I need to save this video first, and I want to copy what the user has selected without waiting for the video to be saved, is it even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okey im find way )

for video

```
PHImageManager.default().requestAVAsset(forVideo: asset, options: PHVideoRequestOptions()) { (avAsset, _, _) in
    if let assetURL = avAsset as? AVURLAsset {
         _url = assetURL.url
....
```

for image

```
asset.requestContentEditingInput(with: PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions()) { (contentEditingInput, _) in
    if let url = contentEditingInput?.fullSizeImageURL {
         _url = url
....
```

and now for image

```
PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromImage
```

or for video

```
PHAssetChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetFromVideo
```

explain:
we cannot copy the asset directly, but we can get the path from the asset where it is located in the system and use it to copy it to our album

happy coding ;)